# C# After Debugging automatic saving

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello guys I have a easy problem but I can't solve.
I open normal project and add something when I try to close without debugging client asks "Do you want to save" but when I use debug then I try to close project client don't ask "do you want to save" just saves automaticially I want to change this options i change a lot setting (tools>options) but I couldn't do it.this situation makes me crazy can you help ?

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i am talking about visual studio

Answer (score 1):

When you start debugging, it compiles the source code. In order to compile, it has to access the latest version of the files, so it has to save them, else the compiler (another program than Visual Studio) can't access them.

Conclusion: there is no way to change this unless you can change the entire working of Visual Studio and the compiler.

Comment: Really,I thought that "i can't find right options there is a well-known situation" for example in vb6 it is very old but you can do it i am surprised

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look into one of the Source Control options that will allow you to revert to older code if needed.

Comment: I looked there and i changed some options but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Could use github, but that's kind of a whole thing if this is just a small project